# Right books for the mathematical fundamentals of general relativity

Tags: general-relativity

I know there are already some questions about this very topic, but my question here is going to be more specific. Are these books the right ones to understand the fundamentals of general relativity? If not, what important topics are not covered by these books?

Functional analyisis (Frigyes Riesz and Béla Sz.-Nagy) Introduction to linear algebra and tensors (M.A. Akivis and V.V. Goldberg) An introduction to differentiable manifolds and Riemmanian geometry (William M.Boothby) Basic algebra (Michel Queysanne) It covers mainly the numbers theory, rings, sets, fields, vector spaces, eigenvalues, hermitian forms and bilinear forms. Some other introductory book to topology and books of calculus (I have only taken calculus i)

general-relativity resource-recommendations education

Comment: Do not worry about functional analysis. That is not the purview of GR.

Comment: I'd also suggest Carroll's GR text. He's a very good writer IMO.

Comment: Do Carmo _Riemannian Geometry_ for an introduction to differential geometry is one of the standars (at least in my university). I don't know the others you cite. But for tensors I recommend you _Introuction to Mathematical physics_, of Peter Szekeres. And don't worry about number theory, rings and all that stuff. For understanding the basics of relativity you need vector spaces for tensors and manifolds for differential geometry. Finally, let me suggest you _Gravitation_, of Milner, Thorne, and Wheeler. In its 1279 pages, it talks about **absolutely everything**, including the basics of maths.